# Grouping with Stata with two or more variables as in SQL GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by, stata

In SQL it is possible to group with several variables:

```
SELECT a, b, COUNT(*)
FROM t
GROUP BY a, b
```

What we get is a table with the levels of b nested in the level of a.

How can this performed with Stata
a) output in windows?
b) stored as file?

Answer (score 1):

If you have only two variables, and you don't need two write the ouptut to a file, you can do:

```
tabulate a b
```

If you want to write the output to a file or if you have more than two grouping variables, you can do as follows:

```
contract a b
```

Print the data on the screen:

```
sort a
list, sepby(a)
```

Save the data to a file in Stata format (.dta) ...

```
save results
```

... or to a tab-delimited ascii file

```
outsheet using results.csv
```

If you want to contract your data, list the result on the creen, and the return to the original data, you can use `preserve` and `restore`. The former "freezes" the data at a given point, and the latter allows to come back to that point.

```
preserve
contract a b
list
restore
```

Comment: Thanks very much. contract is the command I searched for. It works also for 3 variables. By the way: is there an analogues command as contract which put the results on the windows without creating a file?

Comment: @giordano: Of course. As shown above, you have to use `contract` first. Then you can use the `list` to print the contracted data on the screen.

Comment: Thank's. That mean that I have to store the original data, build the results with contract, list the results and clear the file to get the original data. I thought there is a command which put the result directly on the screen.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I got used with this commands and now this is all trivial.